# What are the guarantees around Chainlink "updatedAt" timestamp?

Tags: chainlink

I'm building an application that consumes a Chainlink price feed.

I am aware of how phases and rounds work and I want to know if a price from phase 1 can have a higher "updatedAt" timestamp than a price from phase 2?

In other words, for two proxy roundIds, "roundId1" and "roundId2" with "roundId2 > roundId1" is it always true that "updatedAt2 > updatedAt1"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with OCR (Off-chain reporting) `updatedAt2` > `updatedAt1` must always hold true.